# Git - bring in only old files from origin

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I have a local branch module_update that I am currently in which contains ONLY the files I have changed since my original clone of origin. What I would like to do now is pull the files from origin that module_update doesn't contain. There are files in module_update which are newer versions of files from origin. Ideally, I'd like to pull all of origin into module_update such that the new versions contained already in module_update remain the same and the missing (unchanged) old origin files are added to my local module_update.

I tried to `git stash`, `git pull origin`, `git stash pop`. The problem is that pull says "Up-to-date". From what I've read, this is because pull only looks to add/update files that have been created or changed since the last pull. Pull does not add back files which have simply been removed in the current branch. I'm very new to Git so I'm not sure how accurate of a reason that is, or how to solve my problem. Any advice is appreciated!

A possible solution: Create a new directory and clone origin in to it. Use cp -n (no clobber) or -u (update) to copy everything from origin to old directory. I think this would work, but haven't tried it. Since I am new to Git I'd like to learn the Git way of doing these things (if there is one).

Comment: what is your current branch

Comment: @Ajay module_update

Comment: @WhS4 you can branch from `module_update` then pull all the changes from `origin` to `module_update` and merge your new(copy of) `module_update` branch and checkout only your files with `git checkout --theirs; git add .`

Comment: @kuskmen Sorry if I am being ambiguous, to be clear: Origin contains files that are not in module_update, but module_update contains newer versions of SOME of the files in origin. Does this effect your suggestion at all? (Just want to check because you said "pull all the changes from origin"; there are no "changes" in origin).

Comment: @WhS4 so you are saying that "Origin contains files that are not in module_update" , but then when you `git stash; git pull origin;` git tells you that everything is "Up-to-date" -> "because pull only looks to add/update files that have been created or changed since the last pull". I think I am really confused so I will wait for an answer as I am clearly not understanding what it is desired and how you are achieving such behavior of git. Strange!

Comment: @kuskmen Perfectly understandable, I am confused myself haha. The gist is this: Origin contains files a, b, c, x, y, z. module_update contains X, Y, Z (modified versions of x, y, z). The result I want is module_update to contain a, b, c, X, Y, Z and origin to go unchanged (a, b, c, x, y, z).

Comment: @WhS4 If this is the case all you have to do is -> `git merge origin module_update` then there will be conflicts in x,y,z just type `git checkout --theirs . `(which checks out all origin changes from files x,y,z and saves yours) and then add all these files `git add .`

Answer (score 0):

In this situation `git merge` should be handy. Did you try that ? 
May be you can refer [this](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/)

Comment: Merge is described as "merge updates made online with your local work". I've been hesitant to merge because I don't know how it behaves in the event that the updates are local and not online. I don't want Git to think that the old versions of files in origin are supposed to overwrite the newer versions inside module_update (I want the opposite behavior).